# Traefik SSL Let's Encrypty in Kubernetes Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, traefik

I tried to follow the typical instalation:

`kubectl create clusterrolebinding add-on-cluster-admin --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:default`

`helm install --namespace kube-system --name traefik --values traefik-helm1-6.yml stable/traefik`

With the config ( traefik-helm1-6.yml ):

```
imageTag: 1.6
ssl:
    enabled: true
    enforced: true
acme:
    enabled: true
    email: "xxxxx@gmail.com"
    staging: false
    persistence.enabled: true
    challengeType: http-01
dashboard:
    enabled: true
    domain: "xxxx.org"
```

But when access to the dashboard or a service of the pod whoami, it show insecure and taking a look of the cert it show that it is issued by and for for the domain: *.example.com

I've been looking for answers but nothing, the documentation doesn't help much. Anything helps!! Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide more informations/steps? I would like to reproduce your issue but I need need all your steps. Also are you using cloud or baremetal?

Comment: @PjoterS I'm in the Google Cloud, standard cluster of Kubernetes Engine

Comment: Did you try to use some online tutorials like [official traefik tutorial][1] or [Let's encrypt][2]?

[1]: https://docs.traefik.io/user-guides/crd-acme/
[2]: https://blog.alterway.fr/en/kubernetes-ingress-controller-with-traefik-and-lets-encrypt.html